# rollback changes created by minitest unit test

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm writing a test case in Minitest that creates a database entry. After the test is run, all changes that the test did should be rolled back. What is a good way to achieve this?

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'
require 'factory_girl'

class TestPostgresqlFunctions < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_simple_function
    Factory.find_definitions
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
end
```

With this code, the created entry will stay in the database. I'm not using Rails or any other framework. The database I'm using is PostgreSQL 9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (requires Sequel 3.29.0 or greater):

```
# Use this class as the base class for your tests
class SequelTestCase < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def run(*args, &block)
    Sequel::Model.db.transaction(:rollback=>:always){super}
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems as if this rollsback all sequel transactions immediately. What I am looking for is to rollback all transactions after a test (minitest) has completed.

Comment: This runs each test in its own transaction.  If you want to run each test suite in its own transaction, there's probably a separate method to override.  Read the MiniTest source.

Comment: Seems like I made a mistake when I tested your solution. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!